# rails routing syntax errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on Michael Hartl's tutorial at railstutorial.org. I am having Difficulty In chapter 5 with getting the routing to work.
If I start with a routes file

```
routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'static_pages#home'
    get 'static_pages/help'  
    get 'static_pages/about'
    get 'static_pages/contact'
```

for each of these there is a test like

```
static_pages_controller_test.rb

test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end
```

this syntax works and all the tests pass but later he wants to change the syntax using the *_path convention.

so now the tests look like

```
class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get home" do
  get root_path
  .
  .
  end

test "should get help" do
  get help_path
  .
  .
  end
```

and I updated the routes to

```
root 'static_pages#home'
get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

but now all the tests fail with the messages

```
ERROR["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2016-06-30     05:02:41 -0700]
test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (1467288161.43s)
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:           ActionController::UrlGenerationError: 
No route matches {:action=>"/", :controller=>"static_pages"}

ERROR["test_should_get_help", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2016-06-30 05:02:41 -0700]
test_should_get_help#StaticPagesControllerTest (1467288161.43s)
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:          ActionController::UrlGenerationError: 
No route matches {:action=>"/help", :controller=>"static_pages"}
```

my controller looks something like this

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end
  .
  .
end
```

if I run rake routes I get

```
 Prefix Verb URI Pattern        Controller#Action
   root GET  /                  static_pages#home
   help GET  /help(.:format)    static_pages#help
  about GET  /about(.:format)   static_pages#about
contact GET  /contact(.:format) static_pages#contact
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am starting to wonder if the version of rails has something to do with this. Is that possible? 4 vs 5?

Comment: I am leaning more toward this. I am not sure when he updated the tutorial but now in his gem files for the 4th-ed he has rails 5.0.0 listed but when I started the tutorial a couple of weeks ago I think I was using the 3rd-ed which on github lists Rails 4.2.2 and In that edition he has written the routes differently. was there a change between the two versions relating to the *_path syntax?

Comment: Yes Author has updated rails tutorials with 5.0.0 last week. It is suggested you update it too which will make further journey more pleasant and error free in addition to that, you will get more new things to learn in 5.0.0

Comment: Submit this as answer. Is the *_path syntax new with rails 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Author has updated rails tutorials with 5.0.0 last week. It is suggested you update it too which will make further journey more pleasant and error free in addition to that, you will get more new things to learn in 5.0.0

update your **tests/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get home" do
    get root_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get help_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get about_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get contact" do
    get contact_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
end
```

I am sure once you update your **tests/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb** you will see green test `$ rails test`

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite these routes so that it can create dynamic route helpers for you as per your test. Write it like,

```
get 'static_pages/help'    , as: :help  
get 'static_pages/about'   , as: :about
get 'static_pages/contact' , as: :contact
```

Read [3.6 Naming Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes).

As per your current route, those `*_path` will be like `static_pages_about`, `static_pages_help` etc. I am not sure how did you get the `rake routes` output like you have shown without using `as` option.

Comment: this isn't working it is still giving me a error:  No route matches {:action=>"/static_pages/help", :controller=>"static_pages"} and this does not address why the root route is similarly giving: No route matches {:action=>"/", :controller=>"static_pages"}

Comment: @mkrinblk what is your Rails version?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not so sure, but what happens if you do this:

```
root 'static_pages#home'
get  'help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
get  'about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
get  'contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

Comment: same thing No route matches {:action=>"/help", :controller=>"static_pages"}